# Ellie's fk isn't working

Tags: rigging, forward-kinematics

I downloaded the **ellie model** from **blender studio** and the **fk isn't working**. I have no clue on what to do. Model link for download: https://studio.blender.org/characters/ellie/v1/
[image]

Comment: See if this question (about the Snow rig, but they are basically the same) helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260892/snow-character-rig-how-to-use-fk-arms-and-legs-controls.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thanks!! Now I'd like to combine both IK and FK in the same animation, it's that possible?? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: I've not used any of Blender's CloudRigs myself, but I assume you would have to keyframe the FK >IK change and then pose your model with whichever set of widgets are active.

Comment: I tried keyframing between them but didn't work. I think it works for specific rigs only. I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OFpKXpvdDU where the guy says that if you're not able to keyframe between IK and FK, then you should try to match the poses. For example, if you pose using FK, when you switch to IK the pose will reset. Now you should try to match with the previous pose that you set using IK. I guess that's it then. Anyways thanks for helping me with the fk thing.